# opening the window depending on the variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, window.open

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
    <button onclick="next()">next</button>
    <img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.-d3JKGX5ZJ3Y3U7ybY8h8gHaE7?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain" onclick="reDirect()"></img>

<script>
maxnum=4
num=0
function previous(){
  if(num>0) {
    num++
  }
  else{}
}

function next(){
  if(num<maxnum){
    num++
  }
  else{}
}

function reDirect(){
  if(num=0) {
    window.open("https://youtube.com");
  }
  else{}
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

I wanted a function that checks the variable and redirects to another page according to the variable.

this was needed because the whole script i wanted to make had the image also change according to the variable, and if the page for the image was not made the function would be useless so i also wanted it to be selective.

Comment: Without checking the whole code, I can see a problem with `if(num=0)` This actually assigns 0 to the variable. In javascript (and C based syntaxes), you need to use `==` .  So `if(num==0)`

Answer (score 0):

comment was right, it was ==0 problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use `const` or `let` when declaring variables. Note that both your `previous` and `next` functions are doing `num++`.
An `if` statement can stand alone without an `else` block.

I guess this is what you are looking for?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="previous()">previous</button>
    <button onclick="next()">next</button>
    <img
      src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.-d3JKGX5ZJ3Y3U7ybY8h8gHaE7?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain"
      onclick="redirect()"
      alt="A cat"
    />

    <script>
      let num = 0;
      const maxNum = 4;

      function previous() {
        if (num > 0) {
          num--;
        }
      }

      function next() {
        if (num < maxNum) {
          num++;
        }
      }

      function redirect() {
        switch (num) {
          case 0:
            window.location = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
            break;
          case 1:
            window.location = "https://youtube.com/";
            break;
          default:
            window.location = "https://google.com/";
            break;
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```